# What is difference between derive attribute and implementing traits for structures by yourself?

Tags: rust

I was wondering, what is difference between, for example `#[derive(Debug)]` attribute and implementing `std::fmt::Debug` trait for some struct by myself(or any other trait that can be added with `derive` attribute), assuming that my implementation is efficient? Will there be compile time difference? performance difference?

When should I use `derive` attribute and when should I implement traits by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`derive` just provides a generally useful implementation of the trait (a default implementation which would often be what a user would want).

You should derive if the behaviour of derive is what you're looking for, and that's it. It's a convenience for generally useful behaviour e.g. structural equality for (Partial)Eq, printing a literal-ish struct for Debug, etc… It doesn't make a difference when using the structure / trait.

A derive is just a special case of macro ([custom derives are proc macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#how-to-write-a-custom-derive-macro)), so compilation *would* be infinitesimally slower: rustc needs to run the proc macro first then compile its output. I doubt that makes any real difference though.

Comment: Might be worth noting the main annoyance with `derive`: [it generates bounds on type parameters even when not necessary](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925). This "feature" frequently surprises people and the only fix is to implement it yourself.